# OpenCV 2.4.2 FaceRecognizer std::bad_alloc exception

Tags: opencv

I am learning about the FaceRecognizer feature in OpenCV 2.4.2 and wrote some code to test. However i get an error on this code:

```
int num_components = 10;
double threshold = 10.0;
Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(num_components, threshold);
```

with this error message:

```
First-chance exception at 0x75719617 in Cs.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x001af2e4..
```

I tried several ways but cant really figure out what are the problems cause bad allocation 
happens. Everyone got any ideas about this error?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem could be somewhere else, on mac with OpenCV 2.4.2 I have no such problem if I do this:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/contrib/contrib.hpp>

int main(){
  using namespace cv;
  Ptr<FaceRecognizer> model = createEigenFaceRecognizer(10, 10.0);
  return 0;
}
```

Are you sure you did not include anything like `#include <cv.h>` or `#include <highgui.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details or it is going to be hard to reproduce the error. Your question should contain your OpenCV version or SVN revision if you compiled it yourself,  your Operating System, wether it is 32/64bit and the data you are using. If you are not using the samples coming with the documentation you should attach relevant snippets of your code (if possible).

Comment: as Koo mentioned, he is only learning. He is not sure if it is his error, or is an issue with OpenCV and so the question here. I think this is the right place for this question and I do not think asking him to file a bug, without identifying the issue is the right approach.

Comment: Ok, I've edited it. Still you need more informations to reproduce bugs.